# Notation: set where functions have a defined derivative

Tags: derivatives, notation

I'm looking for the notation of a set where functions have a defined derivative, which only mean that the derivatives are not $\pm\infty$. I know that $\mathcal{C}^{n}$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, would be a set where functions respect the condition of having a defined derivative, but it also give conditions on the continuities of functions and their derivatives. My problem is that I don't assume any continuities on functions and I fear that using $\mathcal{C}^{n}$ would be to strong as a condition. That's why I wonder if there's a notation for a set where functions have defined derivatives, but doesn't imply continuities.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function whose derivative exists everywhere but is not continuous?

Comment: No, and that's the point. I didn't suppose that the derivative was defined everywhere. It could be defined only at some points.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If we take the Heaviside function which is 0 for all $x<0$ and 1 for all $x>0$ At 0 the function is not continuous, but the derivative can still be defined as 0 for all $x\neq0$.

Comment: So you want the derivative to exist at every point of the domain of f?

Comment: No. I understand that if a function have a discontinuities, then the derivative is  not defined at this point. I also understand that even if the function is continuous, it's possible that the derivative won't be defined at some points. I don't care about the continuity of the function, I only care about the fact, that the derivative at some points of the function is defined. That's why I think $\mathcal{C}^{n}$ is too strong.

Comment: So you want the derivative to exist for at least a point of the domain?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. At least one point. I'm interested in how would a set of function with a derivative that exist for at least a point of the function's domain would be note.

Comment: If You know the set on which You want derivability, wouldnt C^1(set) work? If you don't then I wonder what use you have for such a weak hypothesis.

Comment: $C^{1}$ would work yes. And I'm not using the set in a particular case. I was just curious if the set with such a weak hypothesis had a notation. I begin to understand that it's probably not useful and so doesn't have a notation.

Comment: I will provide an answer in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write $C^1(S)$ where $S$ is the set on which you want the derivative to exist.

For example, if you want your function to admit a derivative at $0$, then $C^1(\{0\})$ seems like a good choice to me.

Answer (score 0):

A function that is not continuous everywhere can not have a derivative that is defined everywhere, barring extensions of concepts. This comes from te definition of continuity.

Comment: I didn't suppose the function to have a derivative that is defined everywhere. If the derivative is defined, it could be defined only at some points.